# Check if Android application is yours or it is decompiled fake

Tags: android, security

Is there any way, to check on server if this is my application sending data or it's someone's who decompiled my app? Note that both my and fake apps may be downloaded by user from Google Play. I have only one idea - in Google Play you cant post two applications with the same package names, so maybe I can send package name to server or something like this.

Comment: why would sending the package name work? you dont change the package name when you decompile

Comment: but the fake application could also send your package name....

Comment: to @tyczj Yes, but fake app would be posted on Google Play, so it can't have the same package name as mine.

Comment: to @karan421 i know, thats why i am asking it

Comment: @SemyonDanilov oh I didnt know you meant that the fake app would pr put back in the play store. I thought you meant just to get around any security you had

Comment: And what prevents the counterfeiter from sending your package name from the decompiled app?

Comment: You might be able to see with which key the apk has been signed with. See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/windows/jarsigner.html for reference and pass that data to your own server. But the cracker might remove that too so it can be hard to get around.

Comment: to @Rajesh Nothing :( That's why I am asking.

Comment: If one solution existed as a DRM there wouldn't be any piracy and the latter exists. Another tip, it's not worth the time to produce it for just a simple app. Otherwise create hardware dongles for expensive stuff...

Comment: There is no 100% secure way of doing this. You could take a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8568684/1321873) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/14023348/1321873) questions asked on SO.

Answer (score 3):

It can't be done without some help from OS - because an app would not know whether it was modified (the modification check itself can be hacked).

The ways I'd go would be the following:

1. Excercise [the options Google Play Store gives you](http://developer.android.com/distribute/googleplay/about/distribution.html) - license check and app encryption
2. Add some auth data to the application itself and verify it on the server (some encryption key). The data should change with each version
3. Accept only 2-5 last versions (for people who haven't yet updated)

This way, any pirated version will be valid for only a week or so... And for someone wanting to use the app constantly it will be easier to buy it, than re-download it every 1-2 weeks.

It won't protect you completely, but will make thievery time-consuming and hardly worth it given the option to buy the app. Enough to convince the users who *would have bought the app* to buy it. Those who pirate things out of principle can not be converted in any case...

Answer (score 0):

there are some points which can make your code and application more safer.

use proguard(see on android devlopment site) it offuscates(other words makes it messy at compile time) your code.

secondly you could use encryption and decryption send some secret key encrypted

Comment: But the one who decompiled my app would know everything about encryption i use.

Comment: as i remember(not sure though) when you decompile you only get class files(src files) .... so you can save your key in res/values/string.xml

Comment: @SemyonDanilov: In general there person who decrypts your file won't be able to find out your decryption key if you use asymmetric encryption.

Comment: @BrianAttwell: but that does not give any protection from copying the app. The whole code along with keys will just be copied.

Comment: @DarkWanderer: They won't be copied. The keys aren't inside the app if you fetch them over the network (assuming this is what karan421 meant). Good point. I should have been more clear :)

Comment: @BrianAttwell why cant "cracker" fetch keys over network? He has everything my app has.

Comment: @SemyonDanilov: Mr. Cracker doesn't have valid account credentials. I assume that the Google Play Store tells you which Google accounts were used to buy the app (it does, right?). And, I assume that Mr. Cracker does not have account credentials for anyone that legally installed the app.

Comment: That's called login-password auth, it's not what OP is talking about :-) Think it over more deeply.